# Charles Proxy Not Showing Same as Network on Browser

Tags: charles-proxy

I went to browser and went to inspect element (F12) and chose Network, however I'm seeing more in Network than I see in Charles. I went to sequence in Charles and most of the methods I'm seeing there is just CONNECT, a few GET, and a few POST. However in the network section (just viewing JS), I am seeing a bunch of POST methods that Charles isn't showing. Is Charles supposed to show that or is there a reason it's not showing?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your browser is caching many of those resources not appearing in Charles. You can avoid cache by:

- Refresh your page with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, or
- Clear caché (in most browsers <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Supr</kbd>), or
- Use the *incognito* mode (in most browsers: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>), or
- If using Chrome: open the inspector and select "Disable cache" under the network tab.